# array output from apply() in R

Tags: arrays, r

Suppose I have:

```
aa <- seq(2,10, length=3)
bb <- seq(20,30, length=2)
cc <- seq(10,11, length=2)

fun <- function(a,b,c) {return(a+b-c)}

out <- array(dim=c(length(aa), length(bb), length(cc)))
for(i in 1:length(aa)) {
  for(j in 1:length(bb)) {
    for(k in 1:length(cc)) {
      out[i,j,k] <- fun(aa[i], bb[j], cc[k])
    }
  }
}
```

Aiming for a faster alternative, I then tried apply() as follows

```
b2 <- rep(bb, each=2)
abc <- rbind(rep(aa, each=2*2), rep(bb, each=2), rep(cc,6))
out2 <- apply(abc, 2, function(x){ fun(x[1], x[2], x[3]) } )
```

This basically does the same calculation as before but I couldn't get the format of "out2" to be in the array as "out". Can you correct the below code so that out and out2 are exactly the same? Thanks so much in advance

```
out2 <- array(out2, dim=dim(out))
```

Comment: I think making it into an array via `dim(out2) <- (...)` and then using `aperm` to permute the dimensions might work, but I haven't figured out the proper incantation

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a way to do it in one step, but here it is in two more steps:

```
#your original code
b2 <- rep(bb, each=2)
abc <- rbind(rep(aa, each=2*2), rep(bb, each=2), rep(cc,6))
out2 <- apply(abc, 2, function(x){ fun(x[1], x[2], x[3])})

out2 = matrix(out2,ncol=4,nrow=3,byrow=T)
out2 = array(c(out2[,c(1,3)],out2[,c(2,4)]),dim=dim(out))
identical(out,out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Though not hugely flexible, you could rearrange the entire problem like:

```
outer(outer(aa,bb,"+"),cc,"-")

identical(out,outer(outer(aa,bb,"+"),cc,"-"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail But I was using that fun() as a simplest example and have something else much more complicated.. Nice trick btw, perhaps there is something similar about parallelizing that chunk of code using some shorts of of parrallel apply that you can share?